# What does ```__revision__ = '$Format:%H$'``` stand for?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, unit-testing

I have seen several scripts with line `__revision__ = '$Format:%H$'` in their beginning. Most of them are related with QGIS plugins. It is reproduced with standard tests by QGIS plugin builder. They are somewhat outdated, but still useful. I am trying to understand which parts of generated code be safely deleted.

Comment: It is probably something that is filled in by the/a version control system, but I suspect you will be better off asking on the QGIS mailing list